# How to add an input integer to update the model field through form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a model that holds an inventory value. I want to be able to add any integer value to that model field. It doesn't throw any errors but I get unexpected results when I post. For some reason I do not understand, the code is multiplying the number entered in the form by 2 and setting the result as the new inventory number. I have tried using both forms.Form and ModelForm for my form. The form I am using is also used to update the Panel description, so the text area for the description is pre-populated with the current Panel description. I'm not sure if it's important but the form input for the inventory is also pre-populated with the current inventory number. I didn't think this was a big deal as long as you delete it and type the actual amount of inventory you wanted to add.

For example, if I have an inventory of 80 and I enter 3 in the input field and POST, the new inventory will be 6. That is obviously not what I expect to happen, I would like it to POST and make the new inventory 83.

Models.py

```
class Panel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50, default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField('Description', null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('Date Created', auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    display = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    image = models.ImageField('Panel Image', null=True, blank=True)
    inventory = models.IntegerField('Inventory', null=True, default=0)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("model_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug or self.slug != slugify(self.name):
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Forms.py

```
class UpdatePanelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Panel
        fields = ['description', 'inventory']
```

Views.py

```
def panel_edit(request, slug):
    panel = Panel.objects.get(slug=slug)
    form = UpdatePanelForm(instance=panel)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdatePanelForm(request.POST, instance=panel)
        if form.is_valid():
            panel.description = form.cleaned_data.get('description')
            current_inventory = panel.inventory
            form_input = form.cleaned_data.get('inventory')
            new_inventory = current_inventory + form_input
            panel.inventory = new_inventory
            panel.save()

            return redirect('panels')
    context = {'form': form, 'panel': panel}
    return render(request, 'main/panel_edit.html', context)
```

I have also tried the below approach (probably the nicer way of writing it) and it also multiplies the number by 2.

```
add_number = form.cleaned_data.get('inventory')
panel.inventory += add_number
```

html

```
<form method='POST'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h3>{{panel.name}}</h3><br>
            <h4>Panel Description</h4>
            {{form.description}}<br>
            <h4>Panel Inventory</h4>
            <h4>Current Inventory: </h4><h2>{{panel.inventory}}</h2><br>
            <h4>Add inventory below</h4><br>
            {{form.inventory}}<br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You need to debug your code.

Comment: @GregEremeev just did, believe I found the solution, although it may not be the best practice

Comment: great, well done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by debugging my own code. Turns out I need to initialize *current_inventory* above the if statements. I'll just use JS to change the initial value of the input field.

```
def panel_edit(request, slug):
    panel = Panel.objects.get(slug=slug)
    current_inventory = panel.inventory
    form = UpdatePanelForm(instance=panel)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdatePanelForm(request.POST, instance=panel)
        if form.is_valid():
            panel.description = form.cleaned_data.get('description')
            form_input = form.cleaned_data.get('inventory')
            new_inventory = current_inventory + form_input
            panel.inventory = new_inventory
            panel.save()

            return redirect('panels')
    context = {'form': form, 'panel': panel}
    return render(request, 'main/panel_edit.html', context)
```

Comment: This line populates panel with the POST data thus overrides your panel.inventory:  form = UpdatePanelForm(request.POST, instance=panel)